# SSIS: Check all files modified date and move only those older than 2 weeks

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, ssis

In my SSIS project I have foreach loop container which moves files from a source folder to archive folder using simple logic to "sort" the files to the correct folders (month and year)

But before I move any files I have to check the last modified date and move them only if they are older than 2 weeks. So I guess I need some script task before executing the sequence container for moving files and do this check. I made use of System.IO.FileInfo and LastWriteTime but any examples will be of big help.

Using: SQL Server 2012 / SQL Server Data tools Set 2010

Any help and suggestions are appreciated! :)
Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    public List<FileInfo> getLastFiles(string path)
    {
        List<FileInfo> lastFiles = new List<FileInfo>();
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            FileInfo fileinfo = new FileInfo(file);
            if ((DateTime.Now - fileinfo.LastWriteTime).TotalDays > 14)
            {
                lastFiles.Add(fileinfo);
            }
        }
        return lastFiles;
    }
```

Comment: Okay that's really close but maybe I'm not testing it right. I added your code to the script of the task but when executed the package it moved the files anyway (which are 3 days old). Perhaps I can use variable for the folder path instead of the parameter string path of the method?

Comment: You can alter this method as you wish, but one thing i don't understand how did it catched also the 3 day old file. when i tested it it catched only files older then 2 weeks

Comment: Well I think its just me here.. I'm not really sure how SSIS works with C# code. Should I put this method within public void Main() method? Then how the string 'path' is set so it knows the destination?

Comment: no, you can call this method from Main just change it to static and pass the desire path you want. it doesn't matter if its from arguments or from hardcoded in the code

Comment: All right! I just called it in the main like this: getLastFiles("C:\\Users\\blabla");
But still takes all the files instead of only one.

Comment: can you add breakpoint to this code and see why he pull all the files.

Comment: Hmm..it reads all the files and their last modified date, at last I can see that lastFiles has a count of 1 (which is correct, only 1 files is older) but still moves all files.

Comment: I think you are using something else then the list returned from the method, you need to use the list and move only them

Comment: Yeah of course..I have to set the variable used to move files to the result from the method instead. I have to find out how :) 
Thanks

Comment: for an additional measure, I would parameterize the number of days that you want it to archive so that you don't have to change code if/when that parameter changes